# Blender Failing to import FBX

Tags: import

I have an FBX file that is 9.36 MB

When I try to import it into blender, blender maxes out my CPU and Memory (Blender is using almost 5GB of ram) for a few minutes then goes back to the scene without importing the FBX.

I get this in the console:

```
erpref.blend

found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\python

FBX Import: start importing C:\Users\Peter\Downloads\JMS20.fbx

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2234, in load

elem_root, version = parse_fbx.parse(filepath)

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 164, in parse

elem = read_elem(read, tell, use_namedtuple)

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 124, in read_elem

elem_subtree.append(read_elem(read, tell, use_namedtuple))

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\parse_fbx.py", line 119, in read_elem

elem_props_data[i] = read_data_dict[data_type](read)

KeyError: 0
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue on a Mac.